# Remove duplicate lines from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Someone deployed a SQL table with the schema

```
ConfigOptions
    name VARCHAR(50)
    value VARCHAR(50)
```

and the following logic for saving options:

```
int i = ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE ConfigOptions SET value=@value WHERE name=@name");
if(i==0) i = ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO ConfigOptions (name,value) (@name,@value)");
```

We now saw that this table is littered with duplicates, and we want to change this.

As far as I can tell, the logic is: whenever the `UPDATE` affected zero rows, another row is inserted. If I am not mistaken, this can be caused by:

- a row by the name of `@name` does not exist or
- the row exists, but already contains value `@value`

So, all rows with same name should be full duplicates. If now, something is completely wrong (and behaviour may be undefined).

Now I have to fix this problem of duplicates, so I want to add a PK on `name`. Before I can do this, I have to remove all rows with duplicate names, only keeping one of each.

In the installer (only the installer is allowed to change schema), I only have SQL queries at hand, so I can't do it with C# logic:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
SqlDataReader sdr = ExecuteReader("SELECT name,COUNT(value) FROM ConfigOptions GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(value)>1");
while (sdr.Read()) dic.Add(sdr.GetString(0), sdr.GetInt32(1));
sdr.Close();
foreach (var kv in dic) {
    AddParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, kv.Key);
    ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE TOP " + (kv.Value - 1) + " FROM ConfigOptions WHERE name=@name");
}
ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER TABLE program_options ADD PRIMARY KEY (name)");
```

Is there a way to put this into SQL logic?

Comment: So your question is, you have c# equivalent you need sql to handle this scenerio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%%physloc%%`, the phys(ical) loc(ation) of the row, should do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM ConfigOptions 
WHERE %%physloc%% NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(%%physloc%%) 
    FROM ConfigOptions 
    GROUP BY name);
```

After this cleanup, you can add the primary key to the table.

NOTE: this will leave you with only one row for every `name`. If the `value` column is different in two records with the same `name`, you will lose the newest record. If you want to change this, use `GROUP BY name, value`.

Comment: The value should always be the same. If it is not, it's just about time to change this and remove all but one value :)